# How to assign names to existing struct fields in inner row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two seq objects.
I am mergeing those two objects using

```
a.zip(b)
```

It gives me schema

```
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
```

I want that schema to be

```
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = false)
```

How can I convert this?

It is an inner row to existing row

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: a and b are seq[String] and seq[Double] respectively

Answer (score 0):

chech the code please

```
a.zip(b).toDF("name","value")
```

Comment: It gives me exception 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported

 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:733)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:671)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3088)